# How resolve an error on my Dockerfile for a project Symfony

Tags: docker, symfony, npm, webpack, dockerfile

I will like to create an image docker for a project with docker.
But when I run the npm run build, I have an error with "encore".

```
 => ERROR [13/13] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                                                1.0s
------
 > [13/13] RUN npm run build:
0.970
0.970 > build
0.970 > ../node_modules/.bin/encore production --progress
0.970
0.976 sh: 1: ../node_modules/.bin/encore: not found
------
Dockerfile:33
--------------------
  31 |     RUN npm list
  32 |
  33 | >>> RUN npm run build
  34 |
  35 |     EXPOSE 80
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

I think this error comes from the install of npm and the package in my composer but I haven't found even with npm run list which function correctly.

Actually, this is my dockerfile :

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
  install-php-extensions pdo_mysql intl && \
  apt update -y && \
  apt install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt update -y && apt-get update --fix-missing

RUN apt install -yqq nodejs npm

COPY ./app /var/www/

COPY ./docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN composer install

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80
```

if anyone has had a similar error, I'm looking for help.
Also, that's my fist docker image I try to build so if you think I can do better or correct lines, I'll take all comments.

Thank you.

Comment: You are getting the error from docker, but this problem is not related to docker.

You will probably get the same error if you try rebuilding your app on your host machine (instead of docker).

Comment: According to your error result: Encore is not installed. Add these commands : RUN npm install @symfony/webpack-encore  --save-dev and  RUN  ./node_modules/.bin/encore --version after RUN npm install command